# Using uploadcare within formspree without using the widget

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to send emails with a generated pdf, i can use uploadcare for the user to specify which file but i want this to be done automatically, i.e. the file uploaded is the pdf. At the moment the form is sending but the my_file part is missing

```
<form id="contactform" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name">
    <input type="email" name="_replyto" placeholder="Your email">
    <input type="hidden" name="_subject" value="Website contact" />
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="my_file" data-public-key="key_here" />
    <input type="text" name="_gotcha" style="display:none" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send">

</form>
```

js

```
            const filetostore = fetch()
                console.log(filetostore)


            async   function fetch(){
                    const itemToStore = document.getElementsByClassName("itemName");
                    const itemQty = document.getElementsByClassName("quoteQty");
                    const itemPrices = document.getElementsByClassName("quotePrice");
                    const itemTotal = document.getElementsByClassName("quoteTotal");
                    const totalCost = "Total Cost" + ":" + document.getElementById("quoteTotalCost").innerText;

            await fn(itemToStore, itemQty, itemPrices, itemTotal, totalCost)

        }

        var my_file = uploadcare.fileFrom('input',  filetostore);
        $('input[name="my_file"]').val(myfile)
        console.log(my_file)

var contactform =  document.getElementById('contactform');
contactform.setAttribute('action', '//formspree.io/' + 'yy92' + '@' + 'gmail' + '.' + 'com');
```

Answer (score 0):

The `uploadcare.fileFrom` method returns a promise-based uploadcare [file instance](https://uploadcare.com/docs/api_reference/javascript/files_uploads/#file-new-instance). If you want to add a file URL in the form, you need to get it first.

```
var my_file = uploadcare.fileFrom('input', filetostore);
my_file.done(function(fileInfo) {
  $('input[name="my_file"]').val(fileInfo.cdnUrl);
});
```

Also, the `filetostore` argument should be a [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) containing a file to upload. It's not clear from the code snippet what the `fetch()` function returns.